# using return data in models django

Tags: python, django, function, django-models

I'm fairly new to Django and Python and I'm trying to develop a small website to calculate the total number of minutes per day on a certain period of time.

So far I made a model containing fields with all the information I need, and two functions in the model that calculates the number of days and the number of minutes in a time period.

But now I'm stuck. I've been trying to multiply the results of my functions, but I can't manage to do it.

I don't know if I'm doing this the right way or the most efficient way, I'm open to all advices to improve my code

Thanks a lot

```
class Vacation (models.Model):
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='test')

    start_date = models.DateField(default=0)
    end_date = models.DateField(default=0)

    start_hour = models.TimeField(default=0)
    end_hour = models.TimeField(default=0)

    monday = models.BooleanField()
    tuesday = models.BooleanField()
    wednesday = models.BooleanField()
    thursday  = models.BooleanField()
    friday = models.BooleanField()
    saturday = models.BooleanField()
    sunday = models.BooleanField()

    @property
    # these are not the actual functions but only the results they give me
    def calcul_jours(self):
        work_days = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
        day_list = [6, 6 , 0, 0, 7, 7, 0]
        return day_list

    def calcul_heures(self):
        day_minutes = [180, 90, 0, 0, 90, 90, 90]
        night_minutes = [540, 360, 0, 0, 180, 360, 180]
        day_night = np.array([day_minutes, night_minutes])

        return day_night

    def multiplication(self):
        days = Calcul.calcul_jours
        minutes = Calcul.calcul_heures

        multiplication = np.multiply(days, minutes)
        return multiplication
```

Comment: you can do something similar to this to get the different minute `minutes_diff = (end_date - start_date).total_seconds() / 60.0`

Answer (score 0):

numpy is a great library but you are about to learn the hard way how much of a !@#$%^ programming in time data types can be. Here I'll save you the headache, numpy has support for [this data type](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html). It might not make sense at first, but you are going to want to calculate things using those methods whenever possible. Another option is python's built-in [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html) library. Hopefully that should help you calculate things the way you want.

As far as efficiency is concerned, be careful about how you use model `@property`s. They are useful for making "calculated fields" like you are doing here, but if you ever put a query inside a property, you will effectively be calling 2 queries whenever you call upon this property. This makes displaying large amounts of data very taxing.